# Is there any way to exclude an object from the digest cycle?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Within my $scope I have a very large, read-only data structure (maybe 3000+ objects in a hierarchy). Since this never changes, and because I want to maximise performance on mobile, I want to tell Angular it can skip looking for changes within this structure within its digest cycle.

Any ideas if/how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out the `bindonce` project [here](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce).  It allows you to bind in a field without creating a watch.

So, as you describe there won't be any two-way binding, and therefore, no dirty-check in the $digest cycle.